# Test is fine but coverage gets syntax error with JSON files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a React project and I installed Jest to do tests.  All my React components, SCSS files, images, etc. are found in the `src/` directory.

So far, this command runs perfectly and all my React Jest snapshot tests pass:

```
node_modules/.bin/jest
```

But as soon as I attempt to run a coverage report with this command:

```
node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/**
```

I get the error below:

```
STACK: SyntaxError: /var/www/html/src/SCSS/fontello/config.json: Missing semicolon. (2:8)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "name": "",
    |         ^
  3 |   "css_prefix_text": "icon-",
  4 |   "css_use_suffix": false,
  5 |   "hinting": true,
    at Parser._raise (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:147:45)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:142:17)
    at Parser.raise (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:91:17)
    at Parser.semicolon (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:127:10)
    at Parser.parseExpressionStatement (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:908:10)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:392:19)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:247:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:983:25)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:959:10)
    at Parser.parseBlock (/var/www/html/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:929:10)
```

What do I need to do to get a coverage report?

I'm using this version of Jest in my `package.json` file:

```
"devDependencies":
    ...
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and I ignore `json` files from coverage

```
"coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["^.+\\.json$"],
```

Add this line to `jest.config.js` or `package.json` to ignore `json` files.

Hope this works for you.